# How to compute the exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

So I have $a^n = b$. When I know $a$ and $b$, how can I find $n$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the logarithm to base $a$ on both sides.

Comment: Do you know about logarithms? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Here, n = log$_a(b)$ = $\frac{ln (b)}{ln (a)}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was really stuck, brain freeze.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}a^n &= b\\
\Rightarrow \log_{a}{a^n} &= \log_{a}{b}\quad(\because \log_{a}a^n = n)\\
\Rightarrow n &= \log_{a}{b} \end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Exponent problems like finding $n$ if we know the value of both $a$ and $b$ in the equation $a^n = b$ can be solved using [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm):

$$
\begin{align}
a^n=b&\Rightarrow \log \left(a^n\right)=\log (b) \\
&\Rightarrow n\log(a)=\log(b) \\
&\Rightarrow n=\dfrac{\log(b)}{\log(a)}=\log_a (b)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Apply Logarithm on both sides:

$$ \log a^n = \log b$$
$$n \log a = \log b$$
$$n = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$$

If you are a starter in Logarithms, you can refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).

Answer (score 2):

$$ a^n = b $$
$$ log_{a}b = n $$

Because the easily accessible *log* button on your calculator is probably *base 10* and *not base a*, you have to punch it in this way:

$$\frac {\log b} {\log a}$$

which will result in your answer, $n$.

If you have a TI-89 Titanium, *Diamond 7* is the way to quickly access the *log* function (it took me a long time to find this).